# AWS ECS tasks keep starting and stopping

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs

I am trying to use ECS for deployment with travis.
At one point everything was working but now it stopped.

I am following this tutorial https://testdriven.io/part-five-ec2-container-service/

There are 2 tasks that keep stopping and starting.

These are the messages I see in tasks:

```
STOPPED (CannotStartContainerError: API error (500): oci ru)

STOPPED (Essential container in task exited)
```

These are the messages I see in the logs:

```
FATAL: could not write to file "pg_wal/xlogtemp.28": No space left on device

container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"./entrypoint.sh\": permission denied"
```

Why is ECS stopping and starting so many new tasks? This was not happening before.

This is my docker_deploy.sh from my main microservice which I am calling via travis.

```
#!/bin/sh


if [ -z "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" ] || [ "$TRAVIS_PULL_REQUEST" == "false" ];
then

    if [ "$TRAVIS_BRANCH" == "staging" ];
    then
        JQ="jq --raw-output --exit-status"

        configure_aws_cli() {
            aws --version
            aws configure set default.region us-east-1
            aws configure set default.output json
            echo "AWS Configured!"
        }

        make_task_def() {
            task_template=$(cat ecs_taskdefinition.json)
            task_def=$(printf "$task_template" $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID $AWS_ACCOUNT_ID)
            echo "$task_def"
        }

        register_definition() {
            if revision=$(aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json "$task_def" --family $family | $JQ '.taskDefinition.taskDefinitionArn');
            then
                echo "Revision: $revision"
            else
                echo "Failed to register task definition"
                return 1
            fi
        }

        deploy_cluster() {

            family="testdriven-staging"
            cluster="ezasdf-staging"
            service="ezasdf-staging"

            make_task_def
            register_definition

            if [[ $(aws ecs update-service --cluster $cluster --service $service --task-definition $revision | $JQ '.service.taskDefinition') != $revision ]];
            then
                echo "Error updating service."
                return 1
            fi

        }

        configure_aws_cli
        deploy_cluster

    fi
fi
```

This is my Dockerfile from my users microservice:

```
FROM python:3.6.2

# install environment dependencies
RUN apt-get update -yqq \
    && apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
        netcat \
    && apt-get -q clean

# set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add requirements (to leverage Docker cache)
ADD ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt

# install requirements
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# add entrypoint.sh
ADD ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

# add app
ADD . /usr/src/app

# run server
CMD ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh


echo "Waiting for postgres..."

while ! nc -z users-db 5432;
do
    sleep 0.1
done

echo "PostgreSQL started"

python manage.py recreate_db
python manage.py seed_db
gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 manage:app
```

I tried deleting my cluster and deregistering my tasks and restarting but ECS still continuously stops and starts new tasks now.

When it was working fine: the difference was that instead of the `CMD ["./entrypoint.sh"]` in my Dockerfile, I had

```
RUN python manage.py recreate_db
RUN python manage.py seed_db
CMD gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 manage:app
```

travis is passing.

Answer (score 3):

The errors are right there.

You don't have enough space on your host; and the `entrypoint.sh` file is being denied.

Ensure your host has enough disk space (Shell in and `df -h` to check and expand the volume or just bring up a new instance with more space) and for the `entrypoint.sh` ensure that when building your image it is executable `chmod +x` and also is readable by the user the container is running as.

Test your containers locally first; the second error should have been caught in development instantly.

Comment: I think there is not enough space because it started and stopped so many tasks.

Comment: Tasks don't consume space; images do - and it would have only downloaded the image once.

Comment: But it was working fine before I tried to automate the updating of task definition revisions.

Comment: @bohee-park; sorry if you want more information than we've given you, you need to provide more information about your setup yourself. Be extremely verbose.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this answer isn't 100% relevant to the question asked, but some googling brought me here due to the title and I figure my solution might help someone later down the line.

I also had this issue, but the reason why my containers kept restarting wasn't a lack of space or other resources, it was because I had enabled dynamic host port mapping and forgotten to update my security group as needed. What happened then is that the health checks my load balancer sent to my containers inevitably failed and ECS restarted the containers (whoops).

Dynamic Port Mapping in AWS Documentation:

- https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/dynamic-port-mapping-ecs/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/APIReference/API_PortMapping.html Contents --> hostPort

tl;dr - Make sure your load balancer can health check ports 32768 - 65535.

Answer (score 0):

If it's too many tasks running and they have consumed the space then you will need to shell in to the host and do the following. Don't use `-f` on the `docker rm` as that will remove the running ECS agent container

```
docker rm $(docker ps -aq)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do docker ps -a

Which results in all the stopped containers which are excited, these also consumes disk space.use below command to remove those zoombie

docker rm $(docker ps -a | grep Exited | awk '{print $1}')

And also remove older images or unused images these takes more DiskStation size than containers

docker rmi -f image_name